# Best way to fix pandas DataFrame with some cell values in wrong columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame where some cells are in wrong columns. It looks like this:

| City | River | Price | Car |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| NY | Hudzon | Low | VW |
| LA | Yukon | High | Tesla |
| LasVegas | Low | Hudzon | VW |
| Low | NY | Tesla | Yukon |

I have enumared lists of all possible values in City, River, Price and Car columns.

What is the best way to fix this dataset and put all values in right columns in pandas ?

Upd:

That is the code, I have created and that worked for me:

```
x = pd.DataFrame({'name':['andrew', 'karl', 'jhon', 'jack', 'bob', 'high'], 'education': ['high', 'middle', 'lviv', 'high', 'elementary', 'kyiv'], 'city':['lviv', 'kyiv', 'elementary', 'kharkiv', 'kyiv', 'mike']})

ydata = pd.DataFrame(x)

fdict = {}
fdict['name'] = ['andrew', 'karl', 'jhon', 'jack', 'bob', 'mike']
fdict['education'] = ['high', 'middle', 'elementary']
fdict['city'] = ['lviv', 'kyiv', 'kharkiv']

filter = {}
for key in fdict:
    filter[key] = {}

for key1 in fdict:
    regexx = '|'.join(fdict[key1])
    for key2 in fdict:
        filter[key2][key1] = ydata[key2].str.contains(regexx, regex=True, na=False)


indata = {}
for key in fdict:
    indata[key] = {}

for key1 in fdict:
    for key2 in fdict:
        if key1 != key2:
            indata[key1][key2] = ydata.loc[filter[key1][key2], key1]

for key in fdict:
    fn = ~filter[key][key]
    ydata.loc[fn, key] = np.nan


for key1 in fdict:
    for key2 in fdict:
        if key1 != key2:
            ydata.loc[filter[key1][key2], key2] = indata[key1][key2]
```

Comment: What is your raw data source in the first place? Maybe there is a delimiter issue order the raw data itself is flawed. Depending on the reason there are different appropriate solutions to each problem.

Comment: I have a dataset which is the result of bad API calls. I couldn't do another API calls and have to use it "as is".

Comment: is there any pattern in which the values end in the wrong column?

Comment: No. There are the same mixed columns for every 20-50 rows (number of rows also changes)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is the code, I have created and that worked for me:

```
x = pd.DataFrame({'name':['andrew', 'karl', 'jhon', 'jack', 'bob', 'high'], 'education': ['high', 'middle', 'lviv', 'high', 'elementary', 'kyiv'], 'city':['lviv', 'kyiv', 'elementary', 'kharkiv', 'kyiv', 'mike']})

ydata = pd.DataFrame(x)

fdict = {}
fdict['name'] = ['andrew', 'karl', 'jhon', 'jack', 'bob', 'mike']
fdict['education'] = ['high', 'middle', 'elementary']
fdict['city'] = ['lviv', 'kyiv', 'kharkiv']

filter = {}
for key in fdict:
    filter[key] = {}

for key1 in fdict:
    regexx = '|'.join(fdict[key1])
    for key2 in fdict:
        filter[key2][key1] = ydata[key2].str.contains(regexx, regex=True, na=False)


indata = {}
for key in fdict:
    indata[key] = {}

for key1 in fdict:
    for key2 in fdict:
        if key1 != key2:
            indata[key1][key2] = ydata.loc[filter[key1][key2], key1]

for key in fdict:
    fn = ~filter[key][key]
    ydata.loc[fn, key] = np.nan


for key1 in fdict:
    for key2 in fdict:
        if key1 != key2:
            ydata.loc[filter[key1][key2], key2] = indata[key1][key2]
```

Comment: Please add some comments on your code to make it obvious how this answers the question. The variables used in the code don't seem to be related to the dataframe in question.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

other solution:

```
cols_list = []
for col in ydata.columns:
  ydata[col] = ydata[col].apply(lambda x: {key: x for key in fdict.keys() if x in fdict[key]})
ydata_list = ydata.to_dict('split')['data']

# dataset reconstraction
update_ydata_list = []
for y in ydata_list:
  temp_dict = {}
  for d in y:
      temp_dict.update(d)
  update_ydata_list.append(temp_dict.copy())

# final result
pd.DataFrame(update_ydata_list)
```

you can test it on the full dataset

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).